# Kubernetes Cronjobs leave the pod behind in Not Ready State after completing the execution

Tags: kubernetes, cron, azure-aks, kubernetes-cronjob

In AKS,my cronjobs are getting triggered, executed & completed but the Pod is left behind in a Not Ready state. I've been using successfulJobsHistoryLimit and failedJobsHistoryLimit as 0. I want to get rid of these as there are some crons running at every 5 minutes and so, generating huge list of not ready completed pods here when I run kubectl get pods.

Here's the cronjob.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: p1
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    app: p1
spec:
  schedule: "*/3 * * * *"
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 30
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 0  
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      name: p1
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          imagePullSecrets:
            - name: sp-regcred
          serviceAccountName: dev-sa
          automountServiceAccountToken: true
          # securityContext:
          #   runAsUser: 1001
          containers:
          - name: p1
            image: pep/eiap/p1:BUILD_NUMBER
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            securityContext:
              runAsUser: 1001
            resources:
              requests:
                memory: "2Gi"
                cpu: "125m"
              limits:
                memory: "3Gi"
                cpu: "500m"
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
```

Here is the python file which I am trying to execute:

```
def main():

    log.debug('p1 test')

    print(f"Starting at {datetime.now()}")
    sleep(90)
    print(f"Ending 3 seconds later at {datetime.now()}")
    sys.exit(0)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the docker file :

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV pythonunbuffered 1

FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/python:3.9.10-slim-buster

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /ARIADNE_FLASKAPI

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /ARIADNE_FLASKAPI
COPY . /ARIADNE_FLASKAPI

# Install required dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        curl \
        gnupg && \
    curl -sSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
    curl -sSL https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18 && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Expose the port that your Flask app will listen on
EXPOSE 8000

# Define the command to run when the container starts
# CMD waitress-serve --port=8000 app:app
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Comment: hi - I'm having the exact same problem - did you ever get to the bottom of this?